# Angular/Typescript @Output with Union return types

Tags: angular, typescript

I have number of components (modal windows) that let you select from a paged list of records from the database. So there is a `course.select.component.ts`, for selecting a course.

The modal also takes an `@Input() multiple: boolean` property that determines whether it will return a single course, or multiple courses. So the emitter is:

```
 @Output() courseChange = new EventEmitter<Course | Course[]>();
```

In some places, I can bind it to a property (Course) on the model, and in others I can let the user select a number of courses.

This has been working fine, but I think due to an AngularCLI upgrade, I now get the error:

```
 Type 'Course | Course[]' is not assignable to type 'Course'
```

This happens when I've bound to the picker as below:

```
 <course-selector [(course)]="training.course" multiple="false" />
```

I know that training.course must be a singular course. But I can see that the selector component doesn't know that it will always be a singular, so it's freaking out.

The strange bit is, the components also return the ID of the course/s via the `ngModel`. So the full html is:

```
 <course-selector [(course)]="training.course" multiple="false" [(ngModel)]="training.courseId" />
```

And:

```
writeValue(courseId: string | string[]): void {
    if (courseId !== undefined) {
        this.courseId = courseId;
        this.propagateChange(this.courseId);
    }
}
```

In other words, `training.courseId` is a string, but the value returned in theory could be a `string | string[]`, yet the compiler (with `--prod`) doesn't complain about that issue.

Is there any easy way to fix this, without rewriting all my components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that the original "training.course" is defined as a *Course*, not as a *Course | Course[]*. The reason the *courseId* worked is because the writeValue method accepts the union type, but the training.course field itself might only be defined as the single type, not the union type.

Comment: You're spot on - training.course is a foreign-key relationship in the database, i.e. a single type. However, this used to be ok in the compiler. So it seems I have to re-architect all my modals to have two EventEmitters (`courseChange` and `coursesChange`) and two Input properties (`@Input region` and `@Input regions`). I was hoping there was another way to maybe cast the type on the view or something.

Comment: You should be able to still use one event emitter. Just updating the type of "training.course" should be enough, or you can put some intermediate logic to cast the item to an array of one size if it is not an array, or similar.

Comment: Yeah, I can't do the first option as the model is generated from the database. Might have to look into option 2. Not sure how that's going to work because it's two way binding in the template:  `[(course)]="model.xxx"`.

Comment: One option is to remove the two way binding and use separate input / output bindings. In the output binding, you can put a function in front of it to do any mapping you need.